# How can I run the kippo honeypot on rasbperry pi using crontab?

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, cron, honeypot

I've tried several different implementations as follows:

```
   05 11 * * * cd /home/pi/kippo/; ./start.sh
   05 11 * * * /home/pi/kippo/start.sh
   05 11 * * * bash /home/pi/kippo/start.sh
   05 11 * * * sh /home/pi/kippo/; ./start.sh
```

I've tried this crontab entry and in order to test if my timezone is correct. I've also tried creating text files to ensure that my crontab is functioning well.

```
   05 11 * * * touch /home/pi/bin/hellotestkippo.txt
```

I've created this text file to ensure and test if at the same time I'm trying to run Kippo can be created to serve as a checker that cron does it's job.

The problem is the text file was created but kippo didn't start at all.

Please help me on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: does the cron job execution user has permission for the `/home/pi/kippo/start.sh` ?

Comment: what must be the permissions for cron job execution? and how can i edit it? by using chmod?

Comment: i can run kippo manually using ./start.sh by calling it from its directory. I just want to automate it by using cron to specify what time i'm going to run kippo. by suing the start.sh script also. the start.sh script is already an executable file.

Comment: what is the user group of the executing user ? which `crontab` are you setting? `sudo crontab` or `crontab` ?

Comment: i tried using both sudo crontab and crontab but neither of the two worked. how can I check the user group of the executing user? i'm currently using a raspberry pi device and my username is "pi".

Comment: What about just doing `/bin/sh /home/pi/kippo/start.sh`? Also, check the permissions of the file.

Comment: oh i haven't tried doing that yet. thanks bro. I hope it'll work :)

Answer (score 0):

try this commond:

> sh /home/pi/kippo/start.sh

Comment: i also tried to implement it that way. But it didn't start at all.

Comment: @Sacheo, that does not make difference.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/rc.local` and add:

```
su - pi -c kippo/start.sh
```

Comment: This would seem to run kippo at system startup, rather from cron. Maybe you could edit your answer to explain better how this is an answer to the question.